# how can i create a date picker in android without dialog box display in android fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker

i want to create a date picker without dialog box to suite my app frame also the user should be able to select only weekends i.e all the weekdays should be disable.

Could anyone help me with how i could achieve this or any guidance 
below is my screen i need to replay the button[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwZsw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use this library [Material Date Time Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options)

where you can set an option to disable specific dates

```
setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)
```

values in this Calendar[ ] are explicitly disabled, specify the days you want to disable